# Ruby String#scan equivalent to return MatchData

Tags: ruby, regex, string, parsing, pattern-matching

As basically stated in the question title, is there a method on Ruby strings that is the equivalent to [String#Scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-scan) but instead of returning just a list of each match, it would return an array of `MatchData`s? For example:

```
# Matches a set of characters between underscore pairs
"foo _bar_ _baz_ hashbang".some_method(/_[^_]+_/) #=> [#&ltMatchData "_bar_"&rt, &ltMatchData "_baz_"&rt]
```

Or any way I could get the same or similar result would be good. I would like to do this to find the positions and extents of "strings" within Ruby strings, e.g. `"goodbye` and `"world"` inside "'goodbye' cruel 'world'".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could easily build your own by exploiting [`MatchData#end`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/MatchData.html#method-i-end) and the `pos` parameter of [`String#match`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-match). Something like this:

```
def matches(s, re)
  start_at = 0
  matches  = [ ]
  while(m = s.match(re, start_at))
    matches.push(m)
    start_at = m.end(0)
  end
  matches
end
```

And then:

```
>> matches("foo _bar_ _baz_ hashbang", /_[^_]+_/)
=> [#<MatchData "_bar_">, #<MatchData "_baz_">]
>> matches("_a_b_c_", /_[^_]+_/)
=> [#<MatchData "_a_">, #<MatchData "_c_">]
>> matches("_a_b_c_", /_([^_]+)_/)
=> [#<MatchData "_a_" 1:"a">, #<MatchData "_c_" 1:"c">]
>> matches("pancakes", /_[^_]+_/)
=> []
```

You could monkey patch that into String if you really wanted to.

Comment: Awesome, this does exactly what I need it to! Hah, I was thinking of how I could do something sorta like that, but I didn't know about the <code>pos</code> param :)

Answer (score 13):

```
memo = []
"foo _bar_ _baz_ hashbang".scan(/_[^_]+_/) { memo << Regexp.last_match }
 => "foo _bar_ _baz_ hashbang"
memo
 => [#<MatchData "_bar_">, #<MatchData "_baz_">]
```

Comment: +1 Very concise. And `Regexp.last_match` is thread-local, so you won't run into race conditions.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to get `MatchData`s back, here's a way using `StringScanner`.

```
require 'strscan'

rxp = /_[^_]+_/
scanner = StringScanner.new "foo _barrrr_ _baz_ hashbang"
match_infos = []
until scanner.eos?
  scanner.scan_until rxp
  if scanner.matched?
    match_infos << {
      pos: scanner.pre_match.size,
      length: scanner.matched_size,
      match: scanner.matched
    }
  else
    break
  end
end

p match_infos
# [{:pos=>4, :length=>8, :match=>"_barrrr_"}, {:pos=>13, :length=>5, :match=>"_baz_"}]
```