# Rosalind: SUBS failing the given case

Tags: ruby, regex, string, bioinformatics, rosalind

I wrote a solution to [this](http://rosalind.info/problems/subs/) challenge based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33223313/1014587). It successfully handles the example case given, but not the actual case.

#### Challenge:

> Given two strings `s` and `t`, `t` is a substring of `s` if `t` is contained as a contiguous collection of symbols in `s` (as a result, `t` must be no longer than `s`).
>
> The position of a symbol in a string is the total number of symbols found to its left, including itself (e.g., the positions of all occurrences of 'U' in "AUGCUUCAGAAAGGUCUUACG" are 2, 5, 6, 15, 17, and 18). The symbol at position `i` of `s` is denoted by `s[i]`.
>
> A substring of `s` can be represented as `s[j:k]`, where `j` and `k` represent the starting and ending positions of the substring in `s`; for example, if `s = "AUGCUUCAGAAAGGUCUUACG"`, then `s[2:5] = "UGCU"`.
>
> The location of a substring `s[j:k]` is its beginning position `j`; note that `t` will have multiple locations in `s` if it occurs more than once as a substring of `s` (see the Sample below).

#### Given:

> Two DNA strings `s` and `t` (each of length at most 1 kbp).

#### Return:

> All locations of `t` as a substring of `s`.

#### Sample Dataset:

```
GATATATGCATATACTT
ATAT
```

#### Sample Output:

```
2 4 10
```

For the sample, it works. Sure, you need to trim the formatting by hand, but that's only a couple of seconds of work.

The actual data and my generated output are not accepted.

#### Actual Dataset:

```
CAAATAGTCACACAATAGTCGGCTAAATAGTCAATAGTCAAATAGTCAGAGCTAATAGTCTAAATAGTCGAAAAATAGTCATCAATAGTCTAAATAGTCAATAGTCGGAATAGTCAAAATAGTCAATAGTCAATAGTCAATAGTCGACTAAATAGTCCCAATAGTCTCAGAAATAGTCAATAGTCGTAATAGTCAATAGTCTAATAGTCTAATAGTCCAATAGTCTGTCAAATAGTCAATAGTCCAATAGTCGTTTAATAGTCCCCTTTACCAATAGTCAATAGTCCGAATAGTCAGGAATAGTCAGCACTAATAGTCAATAGTCCTAATAGTCCCAATAGTCAAAATAGTCAATAGTCTAAATAATAGTCCTAGCAGAAGAATAGTCTAATAGTCGGCAATAGTCAATAGTCAAATAGTCAGAATAGTCAAATAGTCGAAATAGTCAATAGTCAATAGTCAAATAGTCAAATAGTCAATAGTCAAATAGTCAAATAGTCAAATAGTCGAATAGTCTGTAATAGTCAATAGTCCTTCAATAGTCTAATAGTCATTCAATAGTCAAGAAATAGTCGGGGGAATAGTCCGAATAGTCAAATAGTCAATAGTCGAATAGTCTAATAGTCAATAGTCTAATAGTCTGATAATAGTCAAATAGTCAATAGTCTAAATAGTCGCCTATGCCAATAGTCTTATCAAATAGTCTCTTAATAGTCTAATAGTCAATAGTCAATAGTCTAATAGTCATAATAGTCAATAGTCAAGGAATAGTCCCATAATAGTCAATAGTCTTAATAGTCCAAACGAAATAGTCTTAATAGTCCCTAATAGTCACTAATAGTCGTAATAGTCATAATAGTCCAATAGTCTAAATAGTCTGCAATAGTCAAATAGTCAAATAGTCCGTACAATAGTCTTAATAGTCTTTGCGGCTCAATAGTCTCATAATAGTC
AATAGTCAA
```

#### Actual Output (trimmed):

```
26 33 93 109 118 125 132
```

#### Code:

```
def find_substring_locations(long, short)
  mpos = []
  re = Regexp.new(short)
  m = i = 0
  m = re.match( long, i ) { |k| j = k.begin(0); i = j + 1; mpos << j } while m
  return mpos
end

def plus_one(input)
  arr = []
  for i in input
    arr << (i += 1)
  end
  arr
end

main_string = gets.chomp
sub_string = gets.chomp
plus_one(find_substring_locations(main_string, sub_string))
```

Where did I go wrong? It appears to be in order.

**EDIT:**
Turns out the problem was a hiccup in the environment. After a reboot the problem could not be reproduced.

Comment: Does the output end in `778 882 890`?

Comment: Your code is correct (although you don't need regular expressions and `plus_one` is a bit cumbersome)

Comment: @Stefan I suspect it's missing a lot of cases, since the input is over 900 characters long.

Comment: @choroba No, the output posted is what I get. The 3 you mention do not get picked-up by my code.

Comment: @Mast yes, they do. Running your code with the above input ("Actual Dataset") returns 39 indices, including 778, 882, and 890.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is correct besides an off by one error. The `plus_one` solution can be simplified.

```
m = re.match( long, i ) { |k| j = k.begin(0); i = j + 1; mpos << j + 1} while m
```

But there is an easier way to implement.
You don't need the Regexp, there is an easier way to search for the index of a substring match:

`String#index` takes an additional argument, the starting index.

```
input = "CAAATAGTCACACAATAGTCGGCTAAATAGTCAATAGTCAAATAGTCAGAGCTAATAGTCTAAATAGTCGAAAAATAGTCATCAATAGTCTAAATAGTCAATAGTCGGAATAGTCAAAATAGTCAATAGTCAATAGTCAATAGTCGACTAAATAGTCCCAATAGTCTCAGAAATAGTCAATAGTCGTAATAGTCAATAGTCTAATAGTCTAATAGTCCAATAGTCTGTCAAATAGTCAATAGTCCAATAGTCGTTTAATAGTCCCCTTTACCAATAGTCAATAGTCCGAATAGTCAGGAATAGTCAGCACTAATAGTCAATAGTCCTAATAGTCCCAATAGTCAAAATAGTCAATAGTCTAAATAATAGTCCTAGCAGAAGAATAGTCTAATAGTCGGCAATAGTCAATAGTCAAATAGTCAGAATAGTCAAATAGTCGAAATAGTCAATAGTCAATAGTCAAATAGTCAAATAGTCAATAGTCAAATAGTCAAATAGTCAAATAGTCGAATAGTCTGTAATAGTCAATAGTCCTTCAATAGTCTAATAGTCATTCAATAGTCAAGAAATAGTCGGGGGAATAGTCCGAATAGTCAAATAGTCAATAGTCGAATAGTCTAATAGTCAATAGTCTAATAGTCTGATAATAGTCAAATAGTCAATAGTCTAAATAGTCGCCTATGCCAATAGTCTTATCAAATAGTCTCTTAATAGTCTAATAGTCAATAGTCAATAGTCTAATAGTCATAATAGTCAATAGTCAAGGAATAGTCCCATAATAGTCAATAGTCTTAATAGTCCAAACGAAATAGTCTTAATAGTCCCTAATAGTCACTAATAGTCGTAATAGTCATAATAGTCCAATAGTCTAAATAGTCTGCAATAGTCAAATAGTCAAATAGTCCGTACAATAGTCTTAATAGTCTTTGCGGCTCAATAGTCTCATAATAGTC"
query = "AATAGTCAA"

def substring_index(input, query)
  last = 0
  matches = []

  while index = input.index(query, last) do
    matches << index += 1
    last = index
  end
  matches
end


p substring_index(input, query)
# => [26, 33, 93, 109, 118, 125, 132, 172, 188, 231, 273, 312, 337, 346, 400, 407, 424, 441, 448, 455, 463, 471, 478, 486, 494, 520, 557, 589, 597, 620, 646, 654, 718, 725, 749, 756, 778, 882, 890]
```

Comment: The OP uses `plus_one` to add 1 to each index afterwards.

Comment: @Stefan I think he means the required `plus_one` function I had, which is fixed by his version.

Comment: @Stefan thanks, i updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not actually an answer, but your code works as expected:

```
s = 'CAAATAGTCACACAATAGTCGGCTAAATAGTCAATAGTCAAATAGTCAGAGCTAATAGTCTAAA'\
    'TAGTCGAAAAATAGTCATCAATAGTCTAAATAGTCAATAGTCGGAATAGTCAAAATAGTCAATA'\
    'GTCAATAGTCAATAGTCGACTAAATAGTCCCAATAGTCTCAGAAATAGTCAATAGTCGTAATAG'\
    'TCAATAGTCTAATAGTCTAATAGTCCAATAGTCTGTCAAATAGTCAATAGTCCAATAGTCGTTT'\
    'AATAGTCCCCTTTACCAATAGTCAATAGTCCGAATAGTCAGGAATAGTCAGCACTAATAGTCAA'\
    'TAGTCCTAATAGTCCCAATAGTCAAAATAGTCAATAGTCTAAATAATAGTCCTAGCAGAAGAAT'\
    'AGTCTAATAGTCGGCAATAGTCAATAGTCAAATAGTCAGAATAGTCAAATAGTCGAAATAGTCA'\
    'ATAGTCAATAGTCAAATAGTCAAATAGTCAATAGTCAAATAGTCAAATAGTCAAATAGTCGAAT'\
    'AGTCTGTAATAGTCAATAGTCCTTCAATAGTCTAATAGTCATTCAATAGTCAAGAAATAGTCGG'\
    'GGGAATAGTCCGAATAGTCAAATAGTCAATAGTCGAATAGTCTAATAGTCAATAGTCTAATAGT'\
    'CTGATAATAGTCAAATAGTCAATAGTCTAAATAGTCGCCTATGCCAATAGTCTTATCAAATAGT'\
    'CTCTTAATAGTCTAATAGTCAATAGTCAATAGTCTAATAGTCATAATAGTCAATAGTCAAGGAA'\
    'TAGTCCCATAATAGTCAATAGTCTTAATAGTCCAAACGAAATAGTCTTAATAGTCCCTAATAGT'\
    'CACTAATAGTCGTAATAGTCATAATAGTCCAATAGTCTAAATAGTCTGCAATAGTCAAATAGTC'\
    'AAATAGTCCGTACAATAGTCTTAATAGTCTTTGCGGCTCAATAGTCTCATAATAGTC'

t = 'AATAGTCAA'

plus_one(find_substring_locations(s, t))
#=> [26, 33, 93, 109, 118, 125, 132, 172, 188, 231, 273, 312, 337, 346,
#    400, 407, 424, 441, 448, 455, 463, 471, 478, 486, 494, 520, 557,
#    589, 597, 620, 646, 654, 718, 725, 749, 756, 778, 882, 890]
```

Comment: I found the problem, it wasn't in the code. Thanks for checking it out!